# Aligning objects to each other in AutoCad

Tags: autocad, pi-diagram

I have two symbolic valves I would like to align in Autocad 2021 (a threeway valve on top and normal valve underneath).
I am trying to create a line between the midpoint of both valves. But if the valve symbols aren't exactly in line you get a line under an angle like the line below (slightly lighter). How can I align both valve symbols?
I tried the align command which sort of works, but it places them on top of each other.

[image: Align two valves]

Comment: Are you aware AutoCAD has snapping options? You can literally select what features to produce a guideline to snap to. Ends, midpoints, vertices, centers, corners, edges etc. If enabled you hover over the feature you want to align the snap to then move perpendicular to it and the snap guideline will appear. You can also hover between two points to make a cross-sectional snap. https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-50383F73-4F23-4F70-B4FC-52D5748D80AF-htm.html

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of the snapping options. But I would like to move the object that it snaps to. The midpoints of the two objects I want to snap might not  be above each other. Then snapping produces a line with a slight angle. 
I would like that one of the objects moves so that the snapping point is exactly below (or above) the snapping point on the other object.

Comment: filter on x coordinate.  Move -> Select objects -> Select reference point on moved object you want to align -> choose filter X -> Select X position on valve above to align with -> pick some Y.  Object will move to the same X coordinate as the top valve and will have a Y coordinate of what ever you click/enter